# GUI for managing GeoPackage (and other geodata forms)?

Tags: geopackage, data-management

I know that the browser in QGIS has quite a bit of capability for managing GeoPackages and other geodata, but I was wondering if there was a lightweight, standalone tool similar to ArcCatalog?

Comment: "QGIS Browser is available as a standalone application and as a panel in QGIS Desktop" https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/qgis_browser/qgis_browser.html

Comment: @Mapperz -  post that as an answer so I can accept it. When I installed 3.x I somehow missed the browser standalone (which I had in 2.18).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser is no longer available as a standalone application, starting with the 3.X releases series. See changelog entry [here](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog30/index.html#feature-standalone-qgis-browser-application-removed)

Answer (score 1):

The QGIS Browser is available as a **standalone application** and as a panel in QGIS Desktop

> It’s also possible to run the QGIS Browser as a standalone
>   application. Like the Browser panel, the standalone Browser helps you
>   navigate through your filesystem and manage your geodata. It also
>   helps you preview or create them and open them in a QGIS project by
>   drag-and-drop

https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/qgis_browser/qgis_browser.html

Comment: I downloaded the standalone Windows  installer for 3.4.2 from https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html . I did the install and the standalone browser application does not appear in the start menu, nor can I find it in the installed directory. I looked at the network installer and it doesn't appear to offer the standa lone browser, either. Obviously I'm doing something wrong. What is it? Thx

Comment: The standalone browser was removed from the 3.X distribution. Poor user uptake and associated maintenance effort were cited as the reasons. See https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog30/index.html#feature-standalone-qgis-browser-application-removed